# need some good examples for controller with visual force examples in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, force.com, controller

need some good examples for controller and visual force examples.

I am not able 2 write the relationship for them as i am new to this salesforce i want more information or some examples so i can learn this topic

Comment: Welcome to the SFSE! Since this is kind of `plz send teh codez` question you will not get good answers. Please try to be more specific and tell what have you done so far? If you are very new to Salesforce try to learm more about it: [Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/), [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/), [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SFSE. I would recommend working through the [workbooks](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/) that SalesForce provide. In this case the "*Build a Custom User Interface with Visualforce*" section.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i want direct materials related to visualforce and controller together materials only. can u please give me a link related to it.

Comment: The workbook contains both the code for the controller and the visual force page. There is also lots of examples of controllers and VF pages on here.